# Is it possible to see or edit several frames at the same time in viewports?

Tags: animation

First of all, sorry for the title of the question but I don't really know how to phrase the all thing.
Here it is :

Okay so let's say that, on frame 1, I have a vertical bar.
[image]

What I wanna do is for that bar to be at a 45° angle on frame 30 but with no keyframe.
So I naturally go to frame 60, put the bar at a 90° angle to make the bar rotate half-90° at half-60 frames.
Is it clear ?
[image]

My ultimate goal is to have tens of elements going from their point A to their point C while only being interested in their point B, somewhere between the two, where all the elements would harmonize in a bigger picture.
[image]

The issue is that I would like to play with several factors like location and X, Y, Z rotation at the same time and won't have easy values like "90÷2" most of the time.
So rather that doing complicated maths for each factor of each element to determinate their A and C points, I was wondering if there was a way for Blender to display the viewport at three different times in three separate windows.
It would allow me to live-tweak point A and point C to adjust point B.
[image]

Hoping that I'm being clear, can someone help me ?
Thanks a lot.